# fancyBox Google Maps Off Center

Tags: google-maps, fancybox

I installed the latest version of fancyBox onto my site and copied the example for Google Maps (iFrame). When I try it out on my site the map information window is in the top left and cut off. I went back to the example page and noticed that it does the same thing there. I know in the past when I've used fancyBox and Google Maps I didn't have this problem. Any ideas?

fancyBox Example: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples (under Various Types)

I'm using Firefox 15.0 on Mac (OS X 10.8.1). I tried Safari and it does the same thing although instead of top left it's bottom left that the map information window is displayed and cut off.

Comment: I think is a matter of where you center the map before getting the sharing link. If you want the info window centered then the center of the map should be a bit above the marker.